# Small quiz is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to build a small quiz, but it is not working out really well.

When I click 'submit', I'd like to highlight the question which turns out to be false with Vue Class Binding. It seems however, that at the moment I actual submit the form, the Class Binding is not reactive at all.

Only when I change some sort of value, it kind of works.

I made a screen recording that displays what I mean:
https://vimeo.com/280435360

The relevant piece of code is this:

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
    <fieldset v-for="(item, questionIndex) in questions" :key="questionIndex">
      <legend :class="{ wrong: isFalse[questionIndex] }">{{ item.question }}</legend>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        asyncData(context) {
            return context.app.$storyapi.get('cdn/stories', {
                version: 'draft',
                startsWith: '/subjects/biology/hl/1999-may'
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data.stories[0].content.question);
                return {
                    questions: response.data.stories[0].content.question
                }
            });
        },
        data() {
            return {
                choices: [],
                isFalse: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            handleSubmit() {
                for (let i in this.choices) {
                    if (this.choices[i] === this.questions[i].answer) {
                        this.isFalse[i] = false;
                    } else {
                        this.isFalse[i] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>


<style>
.wrong {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is how array reactivity work. Read caveats section from [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

To fix you need to use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)/[vm.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set)

```
this.$set(this.isFalse, i, false)
```